# How to avoid duplicate values from dataset in texbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written a function like below

```
private void PrepUpdate()
{
    LicenceBL lbl = new LicenceBL(0);
    DataSet lds = new DataSet();
    lbl.FetchForEdit(lds, AgentId,BrokerId);
    string output ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < lds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        output = output + lds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LicenceTypesNames"].ToString();
        output += (i < lds.Tables[0].Rows.Count) ? "," : string.Empty;
    }
    txtLicenseType.Text = output;
}
```

It fetch all the `LicenceTypesNames` from `dataset` and split them with ',' and then places them in textbox. If `dataset` contains duplicate entries for `licencetypesnames` column, they are also inserted in the textbox... Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HashSet<string>`, which takes only unique values in the `Add` method

```
private void PrepUpdate()
{
    LicenceBL lbl = new LicenceBL(0);
    DataSet lds = new DataSet();
    lbl.FetchForEdit(lds, AgentId,BrokerId);

    HashSet<string> values = new HashSet<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        values.Add(lds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LicenceTypesNames"].ToString());
    }

    txtLicenseType.Text = string.Join(", ", values.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `Linq` approach

```
var ltnList = lds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                .Select(x => x.Field<string>("LicenceTypesNames"));
txtLicenseType.Text = string.Join(",", ltnList.Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use dataview for that;

```
DataView dv = new DataView(lds.Tables[0]);
DataTable dtLtn = dv.ToTable(true, "LicenceTypesNames");
```

> dtLtn will be consist of distinct values of LicenceTypesNames, then
>   you can use for loop in the same way